# How do I use the rand functions output in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, if-statement, random

I am trying to create a slot machine where I have to generate 3 random numbers from 2 - 7 and then use that output to give different outcomes. For example if the output is 777 and then your bet gets multiplied by 10, if it's 222 then it gets multiplied by 5. I can't seem to get the output of the rand function into a variable to use it and its not calculating properly.

Code:

**This is not the full code**

```
if (bet <= 2000)
    {
        std::cout << endl;

        int game_num = 0;
        srand (0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << (rand() % 1) + 2;
        std::cout << endl;

        if (game_num == 777)
        {
            bet = bet * 10;
            std::cout << "You Won: " << bet << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        else if (game_num == 222 || 333 || 444 || 555 || 666)
        {
            bet = bet * 5;
            std::cout << "You Won: " << bet << endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: The expression  `game_num == 222 || 333 || 444 || 555 || 666` is equivalent to `(game_num == 222) || true`.

Comment: `rand%1` always gives 0, so `(rand() % 1) + 2` always gives 2.

Comment: In your code, the gamenum variable is always 0, you never modify it.

Comment: Before you think about how to use if else I suggest you to confirm how game_num gets its value.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you aren’t seeding the random number generator properly in this situation.

This will always return the same sequence of random numbers every time the program runs.

```
srand(0)
```

You want to seed the random number generator with a new value each time the program is run.

Using the timestamp at runtime will enable that behavior.

```
srand(time(0))
```

Comment: Note that seeding with the current time is a terrible idea. Seconds are incredibly long, you'll get the same seed for a lot of different runs that you could do within a second.

Comment: Good point Marcus. As a video game programmer, using the current time for srand is the best practice. Not applicable in all situations though.

Comment: um, never seen an actual game use `rand` nor saw `time` being used as seed. Especially in a video game context, that's a bad idea.

Comment: A few games I’ve worked on that use that method: Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen, Scooby Doo Who’s Watching Who, Destroy all Humans,

Comment: I should add that I’m not saying you’re wrong.

Comment: Just discussing it. Taking your points into mind.

Comment: How would you do a random seed? Unix Epoch?

Comment: So the trick is instead of using time as seed (and time is practically the opposite of random, independent, and different every time you ask, right), you ask your operating system for a few bits of actually random values. All modern OSes provide some API for that, and so, C++ allows you to get a seed through standard means, see my answer. Still upvoted yours, because it hits the seed nail on its proverbial head!

Comment: The funny thing is that at the time, Tim Morten was my boss. That’s Tim Morten, lead producer of StarCraft II. I wonder how that game generates random numbers lol

Comment: probably exactly this way: use the random your OS gives you for a seed, and run your own PRNG from that. it's a fairly standard way (which is why in C++11 it finally became part of C++'s standard lib).

Comment: Love your games, and also Tim Morten's games!

Answer (score 3):

Dan's answer is correct, you're using the same seed every time, so every sequence of numbers is identical. You need to seed with a random value. Time as source of randomness isn't great in terms of being random, but it's working unless you run twice in the same second (due to `time()` only counting seconds, and seconds being ... long for modern computers, unlike 1970's computers, when that way of seeding was invented).

So, instead, honestly, don't use `srand` or `rand` **at all**. They're really bad random number generators to begin with, and their dependence on "hidden" state makes them a nightmare to deal with. Simply. Ignore their existence!

C++ brings its own random facilities:

You want a *uniform integer distribution*, so use [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Seed with an actual random value from actual randomness-generating events.

```cpp
#include <random>

// … 
// Somewhen before you need the random numbers, not every time:

    // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::random_device real_random;  
    // Set up the generator for random bits, seed it from the actual random 
    std::mt19937 gen(real_random());
    // Use that to generate random numbers in [2,7]
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(2, 7);

// Where you need the randomness:
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << distrib(gen) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a lot better! How would I use that output now in the if else statement to calculate the different outputs?

Comment: you wouldn't use the *output*. It's really not clear what you want to do there, but if you want to *generate* a (pseudo)random number, you call `distrib(gen)` in the place you need it. If you want to save the value of a random number, you just put it in a variable: `int chosen_by_fair_dice_roll = distrib(gen);`